# SQL how to get the same name on column x but not on column y

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause

i use SQL server 2008 R2

I have a table `CarLettre` like this:

```
Exp     Desti       Ville         Date
---------------------------------------------------
MDPR    GGE LAM     BAYEUX        01/01/2014 12:14
MDPR    GGE azM     RETEDD        01/01/2014 12:14
MDPR    GGE AUT     BOGER         02/01/2014 12:13
DAC     LAM GGE     BAYEUX        01/01/2014 12:15
DAC     GGE erT     HUIDFD        02/01/2014 12:13
DAC     AUT GGE     BOGER         02/01/2014 12:12
```

As you can see on the table I got the same column ville with the same data BAYEUX and  BOGER.

How can I get the list with the same name of Ville but not the same name of Exp?

Of course I can get like this:

```
SELECT Ville, Date FROM Carlettre where Exp = 'MDPR'
intersect 
SELECT Ville, Date FROM Carlettre where Exp = 'DAC'
```

but when i do that, i can not get Exp and Desti column on my list

and i want to get like this:

```
   Exp     Desti        Ville           Date
    MDPR    GGE LAM     BAYEUX        01/01/2014 12:14
    DAC     LAM GGE     BAYEUX        01/01/2014 12:15
    MDPR    GGE AUT     BOGER         02/01/2014 12:13  
    DAC     AUT GGE     BOGER         02/01/2014 12:12
```

Comment: Can you provide the desired result for the provided data.

Comment: For Exp = MDPR, what makes GGE LAM preferable to GGE azM?

Comment: Exp = Sender and Desti = Destination...so MDPR had send a packgae to GGE LAM and GGE AzM

Comment: which platform are you using, oracle, sql server, mysql ?

Comment: `date` is different in result of both queries which are intersecting and as per my knowledge, intersection will return only common `(Ville, Date)` combination so it shouldn't return a row... is it really returning rows? I am running same query with given sample data, it returns nothing. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get records for which exist another matching record. There are several ways to solve this. A very simple approach is this where you select thrice from the same table:

```
select *
from carlettre 
where exp in ('mdpr','dac')
and ville in (select ville from carlettre where exp  = 'mdpr')
and ville in (select ville from carlettre where exp  = 'dac');
```

In order to query the same table only twice you can do:

```
select *
from carlettre 
where exp in ('mdpr','dac')
and exists
(
  select *
  from carlettre other
  where other.ville = carlettre.ville
  and
  (
    carlettre.exp = 'mdpr' and other.exp = 'dac'
    or
    carlettre.exp = 'dac' and other.exp = 'mdpr'
  )
);
```

Or simply:

```
select *
from carlettre 
where exp in ('mdpr','dac')
and ville in
(
  select ville
  from carlettre 
  where exp in ('mdpr','dac')
  group by ville
  having count(distinct exp) = 2
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table CarLettre
(
    [Exp] varchar(10), 
    Desti varchar(20), 
    Ville varchar(20), 
    [date] datetime
);

insert into CarLettre ([Exp], Desti, Ville, [Date]) values
('MDPR', 'GGE LAM', 'BAYEUX', '01/01/2014 12:14'),
('MDPR', 'GGE azM', 'RETEDD', '01/01/2014 12:14'),
('MDPR', 'GGE AUT', 'BOGER', ' 02/01/2014 12:13'),
('DAC', 'LAM GGE', 'BAYEUX', '01/01/2014 12:15'),
('DAC', 'GGE erT', 'HUIDFD', '02/01/2014 12:13'),
('DAC', 'AUT GGE', 'BOGER', '02/01/2014 12:12');

with ranked as
(
    select *
    , rank() over (partition by ville order by [exp]) [rank]
    from CarLettre
)
select *
from CarLettre c
where exists (
    select *
    from ranked r
    where r.ville = c.ville
    and r.[rank] > 1
)
```

Result:

```
Exp     Desti       Ville   Date
---------------------------------------------------
MDPR    GGE LAM     BAYEUX  2014-01-01 12:14:00.000
MDPR    GGE AUT     BOGER   2014-02-01 12:13:00.000
DAC     LAM GGE     BAYEUX  2014-01-01 12:15:00.000
DAC     AUT GGE     BOGER   2014-02-01 12:12:00.000
```

Check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31959/1)